# Representation of the velocity field

Tags: fluid-dynamics, spacetime-dimensions, vector-fields

Im trying to understand this line given by our prof. :
"Representing fluid parameters as a function of the spatial coordinates($x$, $y$, $z$) and time $t$.

For example:
$$\vec{V} = u(x,y,z,t) \vec{i} + v(x,y,z,t) \vec{j} + w(x,y,z,t)\vec{k}$$

NOTE: $\vec{i}$, $\vec{j}$ and $\vec{k}$ are the unit vectors.

So my question is how come the $x$ coordinate is represented as function of all spatial coordinates and time $u(x,y,z,t)$. (similarly for $y$ and $z$).

Comment: $u(x,y,z,t)$ is not the $x$ coordinate. It is the velocity along the $x$ coordinate and can be a function of both space and time.

Comment: Can you give me an example

Comment: I dont understand how the velocity along the x coordinate can be a function of space and time

Comment: This is a really crude example but it illustrates the point: Imagine you are in Los Angeles where the wind is blowing from West to East at 20 mph. At the same time, the wind in New York City is blowing from South to North at 5 mph. In New York City, the wind along the West-East direction is zero. This demonstrates how velocity can be a function of space. To illustrate the same thing with time, just think about how the wind speed and direction changes from day to day.

Comment: @OSE Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u(x,y,z,t)$ is the velocity along the $x$ coordinate and can be a function of both space and time. This can be a little difficult to visualize so here is an example relating to everyday life:

Imagine you are in Los Angeles where the wind is blowing from West to East at 20 mph. At the same time, the wind in New York City is blowing from South to North at 5 mph. In New York City, the wind along the West-East direction is zero. This demonstrates how velocity can be a function of space.

To illustrate how velocity can be a function of time, just think about how the wind speed and direction changes from day to day.